# MaybeSubject: conditionally apply shareReplay() on inner observable

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I am trying to create conditional-like BehaviorSubject, which persistant state depends on the message - some message should stay in queue, some should not.

This code should print Fire N1 as well.

```
import { filter, map, publish, shareReplay, switchMap, share, multicast } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, Subject, Subscription, iif, of, ConnectableObservable, ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';


export interface IMessage {
  message: string;
  retain: boolean;
}

 const messageGenerator = new Subject<IMessage>();

 const observer = messageGenerator.asObservable().pipe(
   switchMap(m => iif(() => m.retain, of(m).pipe(shareReplay(1)), of(m))),   
   publish()
) as ConnectableObservable<IMessage>;

observer.connect();

// should go for subscriber 1
messageGenerator.next({message: 'Fire N1', retain: true});

observer.subscribe(ev => console.log('Subscriber 1: Received!', ev.message));

// should go for subscriber 1
messageGenerator.next({message: 'Fire N2', retain: false});

observer.subscribe(ev => console.log('Subscriber 2: Received!', ev.message));

// should go for subscribers 1 & 2
messageGenerator.next({message: 'Fire N3', retain: false});
```

Comment: You're creating a new `shareReplay(1)` with a new `ReplaySubject()` on every emission from `messageGenerator`. You probably want to keep that part in a separate variable.

Comment: @martin actually it's a simplified version of what I'm trying to archieve. Here is the more complex one https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ecv9rg?file=index.ts

Comment: You have the same issue there as well

Comment: Yep, and by exactly same reason - switchMap subscribes only once